# Objective-C method parameter type-safety

Tags: objective-c, type-safety

If I have methods like:

```
- (BOOL)isValidRow:(NSDictionary*)contentVersionRow
```

do we really have to continually check like this at the beginning of the method

```
if(![contentVersionRow isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Handle unusual situation - probably return NO in this case
}
```

to really implement proper type-safety inside Objective-C methods? Because in theory the parameter is not guaranteed to point to an NSDictionary object, is this correct?

EDIT: So answers so far seem to indicate we should not check for this, but then what is the difference between checking for this and checking for nil parameter, which I assume we should do? Or should we not check for nil either, if it's not normally expected? Both cases cover the situation of a misbehaving caller.

Comment: It's really the caller's responsibility to make sure they are passing the right type to the method.

Comment: Usually, xCode IDE itself starts giving you warning or error when caller try to mismatch parameter.

Comment: You just have to check for nil, IDE will warn you if there is a mismatch and if the object isn't able to converted

Comment: This is not how a dynamic language works. You can easily pass your own custom object and it can work and it can be expected behavior. In dynamic languages the type is decided not by the name of a class but by the methods the instance has. You should program a while in javascript to understand it :)

Comment: Well i learned something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in C you are dealing with pointers in Objective-C. So saying `NSDictionary *` simply means "here's a pointer to a memory address that contains an instance of NSDictionary".

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
- (void)useDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end

@implementation Test
- (void)useDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSLog(@"Keys: %@", [dictionary allKeys]);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];

        // 1: This works fine
        [test useDictionary:@{@"key": @"value"}];

        // 2: This will cause a compiler warning (or error depending on the options passed to the compiler)
        [test useDictionary:@"not a dictionary"];

        // 3: This will compile without any warnings
        [test useDictionary:(NSDictionary *)@"not a dictionary"];
    }
}
```

The 2nd and 3rd examples will cause the program to crash at runtime. So if you want to pass incorrect things to methods, you can. Usually Xcode will warn you if you have a type-mismatch.

**Update about nil-checking**: If it's an API-misuse to pass nil to your method, then throw an exception. That's what exceptions are for in Objective-C: to catch **programming** mistakes, not to handle expected runtime issues (like an unreachable network). If your method can just silently fail if nil is passed in or handle it in a sensible way, then do that instead. For example if you have a method `addValue:(NSNumber *)number` that adds the given value to a sum then it wouldn't be a big deal if someone called it with `nil`: Just don't add anything :)

Comment: If I want to expose an API that is guaranteed *to not fail* inside my API's method code (i.e. can't fail with any unhandled exception) even if misbehaving callers send in pointers of the wrong type... what is the best way to achieve that goal? I'm looking to make the methods rock-solid, independent of what any caller can throw at them. Is this something that's just an unrealistic goal in a dynamically-typed language?

Comment: I think it is an unrealistic goal. Think of it this way: How can I make a car that cannot be used to run over pedestrians? How can I make a knife that can't be used to stab somebody? If someone _wants_ to _intentionally_ misuse your API then they shouldn't be surprised if it blows up. Sometimes there's just no sensible way to recover from a grossly misused API call: My "addEventToCalendar" method expects an "MyEvent" object, but I pass in an instance of UIView. Well, it will blow up, there's no way to handle this in a way that makes sense. There's a grave programming error, so it should crash.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you shouldn’t.

Obj-C is a dynamic language, so it is up to each object to determine if it responds to a certain method. It is bad style to check the class of an object.

Instead, if you want to check that an object supports a selector you should use `-respondsToSelector:`, but only if you handle objects not responding to that selector.

Comment: Exactly, there are some specific cases when you need to check the type (e.g. when parsing a JSON) but that's rare.